# Putting two separated lines of text within a single inline div

Tags: html, css

I am making an "alien languages" database on a forum using custom BBCodes.  It displays a block of text in an alien language if the user has the font.  I need to have a link to the font and for formatting reasons I need to have that link in the form of a question mark located either above or below the alien text (doesn't really matter), both the question mark and the text need to be on the same line relative to the rest of the page, and the div cannot break the line outside the div.

My attempt did not work:

```
    <div style="white-space:nowrap">
    <div style="display:inline;">
    <a href="http://f.tarazedi.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=24" title="Can't see this?  Download the font." style="font-size:5pt; font-family:Small Fonts, Tahoma;color:#333333">?</a></div>
    <div class="l" style="font-size:150%;display:inline; white-space:nowrap;"><strong>{TEXT}</strong></div></div>
```

Link to [Example usage](http://f.tarazedi.com/viewtopic.php?t=181) (see the red boxes and the question mark currently after the text rather than above).

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose simple css like `float: left` on the ? div would work?

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap">
  <div style="float: left;">
    <a href="http://f.tarazedi.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=24" title="Can't see this?  Download the font."
       style="font-size:5pt; font-family:Small Fonts, Tahoma;color:#333333">?</a>
  </div>
  <div class="l" style="font-size:150%; display:inline; white-space:nowrap;">
    <strong>{TEXT}</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, the ? does shove to the left but the {TEXT} is still not on the next line and also the div breaks external text lines.  (I also tried it without nowrap).

Comment: This works:

    <div style="display:inline-block;margin:0px;padding:0px;vertical-align:top">
    <div class="l" style="font-size:150%; line-height: 80%; margin:0px; padding:0px; display:inline;">
    <strong>{TEXT}</strong>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline; margin:0px; padding:0px; line-height:80%"><br>
    <a href="http://f.tarazedi.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=24" title="Can't see this?  Download the font."
       style="font-size:5pt; font-family:Small Fonts, Tahoma;">?</a></div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `<sup>` tag? Something like this:

```
<strong>{TEXT}</strong><sup><a href="http://www.google.com">?</a></sup>
```

Comes out like:

**{TEXT}**<sup>[?](http://www.google.com)</sup>